# Collection Getting Empty When Calling the Base Class Method

Tags: c#

I have a base call BaseViewModel which consists of a IList collection as shown below:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
    private IList<BrokenRule> _brokenRules = new List<BrokenRule>();                    

    public IList<BrokenRule> BrokenRules
    {
        get { return _brokenRules; }
        set { _brokenRules = value;  }
    }     

    public void ShowBrokenRules()
    {
        _brokenRulePresenter.Present(_brokenRules);           
    }
}
```

My view model UserEditViewModel inherits from the BaseViewModel. The validation engine validate the model and populate the broken rules. When I call the ShowBrokenRules from the concrete class (UserEditViewModel) then the broken rules collection does not contain anything.

UserEditViewModel Save Method:

```
private void Save(UserEditViewModel userEditViewModel)
{
    bool isValid = ValidationEngine.Validate(this.UserViewModel); // 

    if (!isValid)
    {
        ShowBrokenRules();
    }
}
```

I think the reason is that inside ShowBrokenRules method the _brokenRules refers to the base class implementation. Am I correct?

UserEditViewModel class:

```
 public class UserEditViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        private UserViewModel _userViewModel;    

        private void Save(UserEditViewModel userEditViewModel)
        {
            bool isValid = ValidationEngine.Validate(this.UserViewModel); // The UserViewModel.brokenrules is populated not the UserEditViewModel.brokenrules maybe that is the problem.

            if (!isValid)
            {
                ShowBrokenRules();
            }
        }
```

Comment: is your `UserEditViewModel` somehow overriding your `ShowBrokenRules` method?

Comment: I would recomend passing the `BrokenRules` public accessor to the `Present` method, rather than exposing the private `_brokenRules` implementation directly.

Comment: The UserEditViewModel is not overriding the ShowBrokenRules method. ShowBrokenRules method is only contained in the BaseViewModel.

Comment: Added the implementation for UserEditViewModel.

Comment: You are passing in a `UserEditViewModel` to your `Save` method, but it is unused - can you explain what it is there for?

Comment: @RB It will be used eventually!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `ValidationEngine.Validate()` on the `UserViewModel` member property of the `UserEditViewModel` instance and not on the instance itself.  This will result in the function returning `false` because the validation failed, but the BrokenRules are set on the member object, not the object itself.  So when you call `ShowBrokenRules()`, it shows the broken rules for the parent object, not the object that was passed to the `ValidationEngine.Validate()` method.